# Remove empty space from the end of a line in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, regex

How can I remove empty space from end of line in a richtextbox

Original string

My code:

```
string[] lines2 = comparedResultRTB1.Lines;
lines2.ToString().Replace("; );",");");
```

Comment: yes, I need to get rid off the empty space between ; and ;)

Comment: That's not what I asked; you're creating some DDL to execute. Does it not execute if the new line is there? It should execute fine... hence, does it matter if the space is there or not?

Comment: I am using this result to compare with my original result. Original result just like 'expected result' above. I used data reader to write my DDL on to richtextbox and also used regex to add semi colomn ; for each line. But after adding each semi colomn my original result changed  and now want to remove semi clomn and use only for after );

Answer (score 0):

Could use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx) to do the replacement. Not sure from the question exactly what you want to do. If what you want to do is to get rid of all new lines and any whitespace that appears just before them you could do it like this:

```
  Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s*\n");
  string input = lines2.ToString();
  string result = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

Comment: What's still the same? Are you looking at `result`?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
lines2 = lines2.Select(o => o.Trim()).ToArray();
```

So your code becomes this:

```
string[] lines2 = comparedResultRTB1.Lines;
lines2 = lines2.Select(o => o.Trim()).ToArray();
lines2.ToString(); // I'm assuming there is supposed to be an assignment here
```

If you don't want to use LINQ you can use this method:

```
string[] TrimLines(string[] lines) {
    var trimmedLines = new List<string>();

    foreach(var line in lines) {
        trimmedLines.Add(line.TrimEnd());
    }

    return trimmedLines.ToArray();
}
```

In which case your code would become this:

```
string[] lines2 = comparedResultRTB1.Lines;
lines2 = TrimLines(lines2);
lines2.ToString(); // I'm assuming there is supposed to be an assignment here
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you have a line break in there, not just spaces.

This works as intended:

```
var text = "ALTER TABLE \"TBLCONCESSIONAIREOFFICES\" ADD (\"CNCO_IRISAUTOCONFIRMINVOICE\" NUMBER(" +
    "2,0) DEFAULT 0     --0: No, 1: Yes;    \r\n);";

var splitted = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(a => a.Trim());

var result = String.Concat(splitted);
```

Comment: The code I have posted works (I tested it before I posted). You must be implementing something incorrectly you side.